# WPF: binding several views to a TabControl's items

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

In the current project we work on, we have a main window with several views (each with its own viewmodel) that are presented as items in a tab control. E.g: One tab item is an editor, and contains the editor view as follows:

```
<TabItem Header="Test Editor">
            <TestEditor:TestEditorView DataContext="{Binding TestEditorViewModel}"/>
</TabItem>
```

Another one shows results:

```
<TabItem Header="Results Viewer">
     <ResultViewer:ResultViewer x:Name="resultViewer1" DataContext="{Binding Path=ResultViewModel}"  />
</TabItem>
```

etc.
I'd like to have the TabItems bound to something in the main window's viewmodel, but I can't figure out how to bind the view's name to any property without breaking the MVVM pattern. I'd like to have something like:

```
 <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <TestEditor:TestEditorView DataContext ="{Binding TabDataContext}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

only with some binding instead of having to know at design time what type will be used as content.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually I have the TabControl's Tabs stored in the `ViewModel`, along with the `SelectedIndex`, then I use `DataTemplates` to determine which `View` to display

View:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ResultViewModel}">
            <ResultViewer:ResultViewer />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EditorViewModel}">
            <TestEditor:TestEditorView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}" />

</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    publicMyViewModel()
    {
        TabCollection.Add(new ResultsViewModel());
        TabCollection.Add(new EditorViewModel());
        SelectedTabIndex = 0;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _tabCollection
        = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> TabCollection
    {
        get { return _tabCollection };
    }

    private int _selectedTabIndex;
    public int SelectedTabIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedTabIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedTabIndex)
            {
                _selectedTabIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also like to use a subclass of TabItem, can it be done with your solution (that besides that looks good)? Thanks.

Comment: What do you use the sub class for? Is it View-Related or ViewModel-Related? In either case, I'm sure it can be done

Comment: Only sort of related to the original question, but this answer helped me solve a problem. Very important to NOT forget the {x:Type viewmodel...} when defining the data template. I didn't have the x:Type prefix and it was driving me nuts. Thanks!

Comment: This will show empty tab headers. That can be fixed by adding a string Header property to the ViewModelBase or create a Interface like ITabItem which implements the header property. let every tab viewmodel implement this and bind it to the header in the view. then make TabCollection of type <ITabItem> instead of <ViewModelBase>.
Some refactor tips: remove the _tabCollection. It is not needed here. Remove the SelectedTabIndex. Just set SelectedIndex=0 in xaml. Still upvote because it gave me the right direction.