# WPF User Control Not Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In my user control I have a dependency property that is not data binding. I have looked over several stack overflow posts and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The Property changed method is never called.  My Code so far:

My user control is basically a enhanced combo box. The DP lives inside of the user control. I am using this user control inside of a Data Grid.

The data context of the user control is set like this. 
    DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}

```
#region ProfileType DP

    public static FrameworkPropertyMetadata ProfileTypeMetaData = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ProfileTypes.Default,
                                                                 FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                                                                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, new PropertyChangedCallback(ProfileType_PropertyChanged),
                                                                new CoerceValueCallback(ProfileType_CoerceValue),
                                                                false, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProfileTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ProfileType), typeof(ProfileTypes),
                                                                  typeof(MyClass), ProfileTypeMetaData, new ValidateValueCallback(ProfileType_Validate));

    private static void ProfileType_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject dobj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass tp = (MyClass)dobj;
        tp.SetUpProfiles();
    }

    private static object ProfileType_CoerceValue(DependencyObject dobj, object Value)
    {
        return Value;
    }

    private static bool ProfileType_Validate(object Value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ProfileTypes ProfileType
    {
        get
        {
            return (ProfileTypes)this.GetValue(ProfileTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ProfileTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

In my xaml file I have the following:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Missmatches}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Target Profile" Binding="{Binding OldProfile}" />
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mismatched Profile">
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Tekla:TeklaProfiles SelectedProfile="{Binding NewProfile}" ProfileType="{Binding Type}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The DataGrid is bound to an ObservableCollection. Each object in the collection contains three auto props.

```
private ObservableCollection<ProfileMismatch> _missmatches;
        public ObservableCollection<ProfileMismatch> Missmatches
        {
            get { return _missmatches; }
            set
            {
                if (_missmatches == value)
                    return;
                _missmatches = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Missmatches));
            }
        }
```

No matter what I try I cannot seem to get the user control to data bind. If any one has some pro tips please let me know.

Comment: "My class that contains the data": Is that what's in the grid? What does it look like? What is `MyUserControls:Profiles`? What does `ProfileType` have to do with this? There could be several things going wrong here but it's impossible to guess unless you provide enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you set up the `DataContext` of the view correctly?

Comment: Yes. The first column of the data grid binds correctly.

Comment: What's the sense of the CoerceValue and Validate callbacks? They don't do anything else than the default behaviour.

Comment: I am using them for debugging currently. I'm watching the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The data context of the user control is set like this.
>   `DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

Remove that. Explicitly setting a UserControl's DataContext prevents inheriting a DataContext from the control's parent, e.g. here:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Tekla:TeklaProfiles SelectedProfile="{Binding NewProfile}"
                         ProfileType="{Binding Type}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The bindings are expected to be resolved against the current DataContext, i.e. a view model object with a `NewProfile` and `Type` property. However, since you've explicitly set the DataContext of the UserControl (to itself), it won't work.

---

So just don't explicitly set a UserControl's DataContext. Never. Any blogs or online tutorials telling you so are plain wrong.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25699347/1136211) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40674448/1136211).